# unmarshalling Error: For input string: ""

Tags: python, suds

Getting `unmarshalling Error: For input string: ""` . It probably means that wsdl is unable to unserialize data. But my xml is well formatted. Why is the wsdl service choking on this xml?

I am using Suds + python.
Here is the wsdl of the soap service:

```
<xs:element name="parameters">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="entry">
            <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="key" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="value" type="xs:anyType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Python code:

```
client = Client(url)
query = client.factory.create('query')
listval1 = {"key":"*:*","value":"*:*"}
query.parameters.entry = [listval1]
response = client.service.search(query)
```

XML msg created by suds:

```
<query>
   <parameters>
      <entry>
         <key>*:*</key>
         <value>*:*</value>
      </entry>
   </parameters>
</query>
```

I continue to get `unmarshalling Error`. Is this because `xsi:type="ns0:string"` is not added by suds to `key` and `value`? If yes then how to add it?

Comment: You tagged your question as Python, but you haven't given any of the Python code you're using. This could be helpful in solving your problem.

Comment: @michael-mior Added the Python code and the error.

Comment: Jerry, unless you put a testable bit of code in your question, I'm afraid that it's impossible to give you proper feedback. The code you posted could really be anything. There is no indication of what libs you are using, no hint on what object are what, etc...

Comment: I presume from the error message that you're using [Suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/).

Comment: @mac I have updated my question to make it more clear. Added the wsdl definition, python code and xml msg generated.

Answer (score 1):

i got around this using the [a MessagePlugin](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#MessagePlugin) concept.

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin

class AnyTypePlugin(MessagePlugin):
    mapping = {
        'id': 'xsd:int',
        'title': 'xsd:string',
    }
    def marshalled(self, context):
        modified = False

        body = context.envelope.getChild('Body')
        query = body.getChild("query")
        if query: 
            params = query.getChild("parameters")
            if params:
                entries = params.getChildren("entry")
                if entries:
                    for entry in entries:
                        key = entry.getChild("key").getText()
                        if key in self.mapping:
                            attr = Attribute('xsi:type', self.mapping[key])
                            entry.getChild("value").append(attr)
                            modified = True
        if modified:
            xsd_attr = Attribute('xmlns:xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')
            context.envelope.append(xsd_attr)

url = "some wsdl url"
client = Client(url, plugins=[AnyTypePlugin()])
```

this way you can control depending on what key you pass as an entry, you can correctly set the type.